# Istio - cannot reach external IP on https with outboundTrafficPolicy.mode set to REGISTRY_ONLY

Tags: kubernetes, istio

We are using Istio with `outboundTrafficPolicy.mode` set to `REGISTRY_ONLY`. We whitelist a number of domains using `ServiceEntries` and a `Sidecar` configuration, and these all work fine.

However, trying to whitelist an IP address and use HTTPS does not work. Here is the `ServiceEntry` we are using:

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: ServiceEntry
metadata:
  labels:
    app: test
  name: test-external-deps
  namespace: realistic-doubles
spec:
  addresses:
    - 54.xx.xx.xx
  endpoints:
    - address: 54.xx.xx.xx
  exportTo:
    - .
  hosts:
    - fakehost3.internal
  location: MESH_EXTERNAL
  ports:
    - name: https
      number: 8443
      protocol: TLS
  resolution: STATIC
```

When we curl this IP outside Istio, we get a response back fine. But in the mesh, we get:

```
root@trading-api-99f85fdbc-vskdg:/app# curl -v -k https://54.xx.xx.xx:8443
* Expire in 0 ms for 6 (transfer 0x561ea5c1ff50)
*   Trying 54.xx.xx.xx...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Expire in 200 ms for 4 (transfer 0x561ea5c1ff50)
* Connected to 54.xx.xx.xx (54.xx.xx.xx) port 8443 (#0)
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: none
  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* OpenSSL SSL_connect: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL in connection to 54.xx.xx.xx:8443
* Closing connection 0
curl: (35) OpenSSL SSL_connect: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL in connection to 54.xx.xx.xx:8443
```

The envoy access logs show this, which seems to be consistent with other requests that get blocked:

```
[2020-07-21T17:27:43.240Z] "- - -" 0 UH "-" "-" 0 0 0 - "-" "-" "-" "-" "-" - - 54.xx.xx.xx:8443 10.xx.xx.xx:48738 - -
```

How do we whitelist this external IP so it won't be blocked by Envoy?

Comment: What is your istio version? Could you please check if http work?

Comment: @jt97 We are using Istio 1.6.4. HTTP works for other static IPs, such as the AWS metadata endpoint. But this particular IP requires using HTTPS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out what I was missing. Adding a `ServiceEntry` alone was not sufficient. I also needed to update the `Sidecar` config to list the fake hostname, like so:

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: Sidecar
metadata:
  name: test
  namespace: realistic-doubles
  labels:
    app: test
spec:
  workloadSelector:
    labels:
      app.kubernetes.io/name: test
  egress:
    - hosts:
        - "./fakehost3.internal"
```

After adding that, I am able to resolve the static IP from my pod just fine!